# Problema ao juntar tabelas no MySQL

Tags: mysql, join, inner-join

**Eu tenho 3 tabelas:**

- tb_carne_lancamento AS A
- tb_despesa_x_receita AS B
- tb_plano_contas AS C

Na tabela A e B tenho o id da tabela tb_plano_contas e ambas tenho um campo valor.

*Eu preciso criar uma view que faça a união dessas duas tabelas.*

Eu estou na luta aqui, mas os valores estão se repetindo.

**Esse é o resultado que eu consigo:**

[image: No momento estou com esse resultado.]

**Esse é o resultado que eu gostaria:**

[image: Modelo de que preciso]

**Código (Schema SQL):**

```
CREATE TABLE tb_plano_contas (
  id_plano_contas INT,
  desc_plano_contas VARCHAR (100)
);
INSERT INTO tb_plano_contas (id_plano_contas, desc_plano_contas) VALUES (1, 'Doação Via Carnê');
CREATE TABLE tb_despesa_x_receita (
  id_despesa_x_receita INT,
  data_mov DATE,
  fk_id_plano_contas INT,
  valor_desp_x_rec DECIMAL(9,2)
);
INSERT INTO tb_despesa_x_receita (id_despesa_x_receita, data_mov, fk_id_plano_contas, valor_desp_x_rec) VALUES (2173,'2015-01-30',1,1826);
INSERT INTO tb_despesa_x_receita (id_despesa_x_receita, data_mov, fk_id_plano_contas, valor_desp_x_rec) VALUES (2174,'2015-02-28',1,1532);
INSERT INTO tb_despesa_x_receita (id_despesa_x_receita, data_mov, fk_id_plano_contas, valor_desp_x_rec) VALUES (2175,'2015-03-15',1,1201);
CREATE TABLE tb_carne_lancamento (
  id_carne_lancamento INT,
  data_carne_lancamento DATE,
  id_plano_contas INT,
  valor_carne_lancamento DECIMAL(9,2)
);
INSERT INTO tb_carne_lancamento (id_carne_lancamento, data_carne_lancamento, id_plano_contas, valor_carne_lancamento) VALUES (43,'2015-05-18',1,10);
INSERT INTO tb_carne_lancamento (id_carne_lancamento, data_carne_lancamento, id_plano_contas, valor_carne_lancamento) VALUES (44,'2015-05-18',1,20);
INSERT INTO tb_carne_lancamento (id_carne_lancamento, data_carne_lancamento, id_plano_contas, valor_carne_lancamento) VALUES (45,'2015-05-18',1,10);
INSERT INTO tb_carne_lancamento (id_carne_lancamento, data_carne_lancamento, id_plano_contas, valor_carne_lancamento) VALUES (46,'2015-05-14',1,20);
INSERT INTO tb_carne_lancamento (id_carne_lancamento, data_carne_lancamento, id_plano_contas, valor_carne_lancamento) VALUES (47,'2015-05-18',1,5);
INSERT INTO tb_carne_lancamento (id_carne_lancamento, data_carne_lancamento, id_plano_contas, valor_carne_lancamento) VALUES (48,'2015-05-18',1,20);
INSERT INTO tb_carne_lancamento (id_carne_lancamento, data_carne_lancamento, id_plano_contas, valor_carne_lancamento) VALUES (49,'2015-05-18',1,5);
INSERT INTO tb_carne_lancamento (id_carne_lancamento, data_carne_lancamento, id_plano_contas, valor_carne_lancamento) VALUES (50,'2015-05-19',1,40);
INSERT INTO tb_carne_lancamento (id_carne_lancamento, data_carne_lancamento, id_plano_contas, valor_carne_lancamento) VALUES (51,'2015-02-05',1,20);
INSERT INTO tb_carne_lancamento (id_carne_lancamento, data_carne_lancamento, id_plano_contas, valor_carne_lancamento) VALUES (54,'2015-05-22',1,8888);
INSERT INTO tb_carne_lancamento (id_carne_lancamento, data_carne_lancamento, id_plano_contas, valor_carne_lancamento) VALUES (55,'2015-01-06',1,30);
INSERT INTO tb_carne_lancamento (id_carne_lancamento, data_carne_lancamento, id_plano_contas, valor_carne_lancamento) VALUES (56,'2015-02-02',1,30);
```

**Código (Query SQL):**

```
SELECT * FROM tb_plano_contas;
SELECT * FROM tb_despesa_x_receita;
SELECT * FROM tb_carne_lancamento;
```

Comment: Você quer fazer uma união (UNION) ou uma junção (JOIN)? Me parece que deseja um JOIN. Estude como funciona a junção que talvez explique o que você diz que é uma "repetição". Para uma união as tabelas precisam ser união compatíveis, que não me parece ser o caso de suas tabelas, e para o caso de junção as tabelas precisam ter campos com valores em comum. Como você não postou a query que fornece o resultado acima não dá para ajuda-lo mais que isso.

Comment: SELECT
a.desc_plano_contas,
b.data_mov,
b.valor_desp_x_rec,
b.id_despesa_x_receita,
c.data_carne_lancamento,
c.id_carne_lancamento,
c.valor_carne_lancamento
FROM
tb_plano_contas AS a
INNER JOIN tb_despesa_x_receita AS b ON b.fk_id_plano_contas = a.id_plano_contas
INNER JOIN tb_carne_lancamento AS c ON c.id_plano_contas = a.id_plano_contas
WHERE
a.id_plano_contas = 1

Comment: No caso seria um join.

Comment: Na primeira tabela o que você considera que seja uma "repetição"? Na segunda tabela como podem existir linhas com NULL se você está fazendo uma INNER JOIN? O que vem a ser soma_total? Edite sua pergunta e acrescente todas as informações pertinentes.

Comment: Na imagem que aparecem o valor null é do excel.

Comment: É uma representação de que preciso.

Comment: Se você observar no link onde está um fragmento do meu banco verá os dados que compõe a tabela. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/v3qPgvijhD1tF7GScL6ix1/2#&togetherjs=pDaJcfcq1B

Comment: Com "o valor null é do excel" você quer dizer que tais dados não existem nas tabelas de seu banco de dados? A query que você postou nos comentários não produziria o resultado apresentado.

Comment: Exatamente quando o dado não existe na tabela tem que ficar como null conforme a segunda imagem. A primeira imagem representa os dados do meu banco. Perceba que o id_despesa_x_receita repete várias vezes.

Comment: Como o que você mostra como resultado de sua query não corresponde à query e também não são exibidos os campos utilizados como crité de junção fica muito difícil ajuda-lo. Encerro minha participação por aqui.

Comment: O resultado da query é justamente a imagem 1.

Comment: Não consegui vislumbrar nenhuma linha repetida em sua primeira imagem.

Comment: Basta olhar na coluna id_despesa_x_receita verá que o id se repete.

Comment: O valor desta coluna efetivamente se repete mas associado a diferentes valores da coluna id_carne_lancamento. Creio que você precise dar uma estudada no que significa junção em banco de dados.